# entity "Students" requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am facing this issue while creating view for `Student` controller, I am using SQL Server and Visual Studio 2019.

I am using these Dependencies

- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor Version=2.1.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version=2.1.1"
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version=2.1.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version=2.1.1

=== Student.CS ===

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASP_Core_EF.Models
{
    public enum Status { UnderGraduate, PostGraduate, Masters, Phd, Suspended }

    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudentId { get; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

        public int GenderId { get; set; }
        public Status? Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

=== DB_Context.CS ===

```
using ASP_Core_EF.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASP_Core_EF.Repository
{
    public class DB_Context : DbContext
    {
        public DB_Context(DbContextOptions<DB_Context> options ) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Gender> Gender { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
   }
```

}

Comment: Do post database table schema also.

Comment: why there is no setter property for Id in student class?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing set attribute ,hence the error

```
[Key]
public int StudentId { get; set;}
```

or

```
[Key]
public int StudentId { get; private set;}
```